# Is it legal to reference uninitialized memory without accessing it?

Tags: c++, variables, memory

Following situation, I have a struct containing pointers to integer variables like this:

```
struct Structure[] = { 
    { &Var[0], &Var[1] },
    { &Var[2], &Var[3] }
};
```

Thing is: `Var` is uninitialized the first time this struct is filled. (As in: `NULL`)
Shortly after (on first pass) the variable `Var` will be initialized and the references will be updated accordingly.

I see no reason for this to malfunction, but I'd like your expertise on it.
Is it legal to put a reference to invalid memory (with array subscript) into an array like this? Or do I need a different kind of approach for this situation?

I'm not accessing the contents of these variables until after the first initialization.

Thank you very much.

Edit:
For the benefit of future readers: `Var` is a global pointer variable, which is initialized to NULL at the beginning. The initialization turns it into an array by using `new`.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that the answer is no, and that some optimizers will break your code.

Comment: "Or do I need a different kind of approach for this situation?" Hmm, maybe, initialize the variable?

Comment: @DanielDaranas I am. However only AFTER the array has been filled. It's a function which is called multiple times.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you for your input. I'll think about it some more, maybe I'll find a less risky approach.

Comment: Is `Var` a reference or a pointer?

Comment: You can't read from uninitialized memory and expect sensible things to happen.

Comment: What is uninitialized, `Var` or `Var[0]`?  If `Var` is initialized to point to "a region of memory that's uninitialized" then your code is ok.

Comment: Can you update your question to show us the declaration of `Var`?

Comment: If `Var` has type `T[4]`, then there is no problem.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Tricky one, that: how can an expression of type `T[4]` have value `NULL` ?

Comment: The standard explicitly states that a reference shall be initialized to a valid object and that no such thing as a reference to null can exist in a well-formed program. Which doesn't mean it might not work anyway.

Comment: If `Var` is an uninitialized *pointer* then this is UB in every direction. if it is a an *array* of type `T` with uninitialized *content* then this is defined behavior so long as you do not *read* the content at the addresses being stored in your struct (or in `Var`) until the storage at the aforementioned locations *themselves* have been initialized. Without more info of the type of `Var` thats about as deep a comment as i can offer.

Comment: Hang on. You say that `Var` is uninitialized ("As in: `NULL`"). If `Var` is defined at block scope and is uninitialized, then its value is garbage, not necessarily `NULL`. If it's defined elsewhere, then its implicitly initialized to zero, i.e., to a null pointer value. Please update your question to show us how *and where* `Var` is defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming that `Var` is a pointer object and that its current value is a null pointer. This is implied by your statement:

> `Var` is uninitialized the first time this struct is filled. (As in: `NULL`)

I'm also assuming that `Var` is not defined at block scope. If it's defined at block scope, and you haven't initialized it or assigned a value to it, then its value is garbage, not necessarily a null pointer value, and any attempt to refer to its value has undefined behavior.

The behavior is undefined.

If `Var == NULL`, then `&Var[N]` has undefined behavior.

`arr[index]` is by definition equivalent to `*(arr + index)`, so `&Var[N]` is equivalent to `&(*(Var + N))`. The behavior of pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of elements of the array object into which the pointer points (with a single object treated as a one-element array) and a null pointer doesn't point to anything.

A digression:

C explicitly says that `&*x` is evaluated as `x`, and `&[x[i])` is evaluated as `x+i`; C++ doesn't say this, so the operand of `&` has to be valid. C++ has a special case for adding `0`, which is well defined even for a null pointer (C has no such special case). But `&Var[0]` is still invalid in in both C and C++, but for different reasons. In C, it's equivalent to `Var + 0`, but adding `0` to a null pointer has undefined behavior. In C++, it's *not* equivalent to `Var + 0`; rather it's equivalent to `&(*(Var + 0))`; `Var + 0` is a null pointer, and dereferencing it has undefined behavior.)

End of digression.

Yes, just computing an invalid address has undefined behavior, even if it's never dereferenced.

Here's the relevant text from the 2011 ISO C++ standard, 5.7 [expr.add] paragraph 5; note particularly the very end:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted 
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from  the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts  of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression.
>   In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
>   array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
>   (where N has the value n) point to, respectively,  the i + n-th and i
>   − n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
>   the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Comment: Can you provide the reference where doing aritmetic on the null pointer is forbidden? Or am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: But if `Var` is an array, and not a pointer, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @MarkB It has to do with the legal definitions of `NULL`.  If `NULL` is defined as `((void*)0)` (legal in C, illegal in C++), then doing any arithmetic on it is illegal.  (And obviously, if `NULL` is defined as just `0`, then `NULL + 0` is legal.)

Comment: Also, `NULL + 1` should be just fine in C++.  Trying to use the results to initialize a pointer won't work, though, since `0 + 1` may be an integral constant expression, but it sure doesn't evaluate to 0.

Comment: May I ask why `NULL + 0` is not defined in C? AFAIK `NULL` is just `0`, and therefore  it sounds like `0 + 0`  should be `0` as well... no?

Comment: @VladLazarenko In C, `NULL` can also be `((void*)0)`.  (It isn't, traditionally, and I don't think many compilers define it this way, but there are some---it was the traditional definition under MS-DOs, for example.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: It doesn't have to do with the definition of the `NULL` macro. The OP says that `Var` is uninitialized "As in: `NULL`". The arithmetic is being performed on a pointer object, not on a null pointer constant, and arithmetic on a null pointer value (other than adding `0`) is undefined.

Comment: "(C explicitly says that &*x is evaluated as x, and &[x[i]) is evaluated as x+i; C++ doesn't say this, so the operand of & has to be valid.)" Seems like that means even `&Var[0]` isn't valid in C++ when `Var` is a null pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I'll do the sensible thing and simply declare the array after the block with the initialization of the global variables...you know, where the references actually will be used.

Comment: @ATaylor: You never actually told us how and where `Var` is declared.

Comment: @KeithThompson Var is, as you correctly deduced, a global variable, which is initialized to 'NULL' upon program start and will be initialized upon first use (and reinitialized upon rebuilding the menu)

Comment: @ATaylor: For the benefit of future readers, please update your question with that information.

Answer (score 2):

Since you aren't using the values until after the first pass, do the right thing and initialize your struct's pointers to null instead. Then put the right values in when you know them. If you take that approach your "is it legal" problem just goes away!

Comment: +1. Actually, `struct Structure[2];` is quite enough. If results of initialization are never used, there is no need in this initialization.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question (forgetting the example code): yes, you can have a reference to uninitialized memory, you simply cannot *dereference* it and expect defined behavior.